# How can I change this script

Tags: c, bash

So I have this script to check if a number is the one I expected to be. But I want to test it with the C program output directly, not storing the results on a file.

```
#!/bin/bash
j=0;
for i in {1..100};
do ./a.out > output;
cmp expected output || let "j+=1";
done
echo $j;
```

The ./a.out is referred to a program that prints a number. I want to check if it's the same as the stored on expected but without using files

Comment: This script doesn't seem to do what you have described...

Comment: What does C have to do with this? Do you really think it matters what language `a.out` was written in? The bash code is the same.

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me (by replacing a.out with a simple echo script):

```
#!/bin/bash
j=0;
for i in {1..100};
cmp expected <(./a.out) || let "j+=1";
done
echo $j;
```

man bash:

> Process Substitution
>          Process substitution allows a process's input or output to be referred to using a filename.  It takes the form of <(list) or >(list).  The  process  list  is run asynchronously, and its input or **output appears as a filename.**

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute the output of a command into the command line with `$(command)`.

```
expected=$(< expected)
j=0
for i in {1..100}; do
    test "$(./a.out)" = "$expected" || let j+=1
done
echo $j
```